# Define a function f such that for x≠0 f(x) =cos(1/x) and f(0)=1/2.does it admits antiderivatives? (primitives)

Tags: real-analysis

Does the function f have antiderivatives? I know that because 1/2 is between - 1 and 1 it has Darboux 's property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: See if you can prove this:  if $f$ is bounded, and for every $a$ with $0 < a < 1$, $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,1]$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$. Do the same thing for $[-1,b]$, $-1<b<0$.

If there is any anti-derivative of $f$, then this would be it:
$$
F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\;dt,\qquad\text{for all real numbers } x
$$
If $f$ is continuous except at $0$, this gives us $F$ with $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ except possibly $x=0$.

In the particular case on the OP, we get $F'(0) = 0$,
but I will not prove that here.
So your answer is "no", your function has no anti-derivative on $[-1,1]$.

The Darboux property is necessary, but not sufficient, for the existence of an anti-derivative.

Comment: Thanks! Could u give me some other examples of conditions, properties that are necessary but not sufficient or vice versa in calculus?it doesnt have antiderivatives on R i suppose not only on [-1,1]